# Android - Application stop when i try call getSelectOpponentsIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-games

I am working on multiplayer games on android, i try to use invite friends functionality but
when I called a method `intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 2)`
the application was stopped and then close.
I don't know what is the problem.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

When the [Invite Players option](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#invite_players_option) is selected, your game should launch a player picker UI that prompts the initiating player to select friends to invite to a real-time game session or select a number of random players for auto-matching. Your game should create a virtual room object using the player's criteria, then start the game session, once players are connected to the room.

To obtain the user's selection, your game can display the built-in player picker UI provided by Google Play games services or a custom player picker UI. To launch the default player picker UI, call the getSelectOpponentsIntent() method and use the Intent it returns to start a Activity.

Here is sample code.

```
// request code for the "select players" UI
// can be any number as long as it's unique
final static int RC_SELECT_PLAYERS = 10000;

// launch the player selection screen
// minimum: 1 other player; maximum: 3 other players
Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 3);
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
```

NOTE: Make sure you enable your [multiplayer support](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#enabling_multiplayer_support) on your Google Play Developer Console.

Visit this [page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting) for more information on troubleshooting issue in android game.

Comment: while i develop the multiplayer game I need to enable multipayer support?

Comment: Yes, you can check the above link on how to enable it.

Comment: thanks, but i can see the problem is when app try to login into android for this reason the clientandroid cannot connect and that connecto to api game, the error when try to connet is:
ConnectionResult{statusCode=RESOLUTION_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{b95c12: android.os.BinderProxy@672f12d}, message=null}

You know how i can fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: you can check what is the meaning of that error [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#constants)